# issue on Maven dependency in Azure pipeline

Tags: log4j

I have upgraded the log4j to 2.17 in my client machine azure pipeline, after that i am getting the error as below. Can anyone help me how to solve it.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Test_Automation: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5 -> org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4 -> log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12: Failed to read artifact descriptor for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.12 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

Comment: Perhaps you are updating for log4j vulnerabilities then why you need log4j:jar:1.2.12?
By the way i have provided solutions below.

Answer (score 0):

Seems SSL issue you have 2 options

- configure ssl
- use non https url for maven repository

*For second option you may use:*

> ```
>   <repository>
>       <id>maven</id>
>       <name>maven</name>
>       <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
>   </repository>
> ```